# Why do cron.php still run automatically in each o'clock when I had stopped it?

Tags: cron

I am curious on this. I had switch off it on my setting->system->cron to permanently stop it. However, the mail will hourly send the mail to www-data.

The mail content as below:

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
Error running the periodic maintenance for /etc/drupal/7/sites/default: CURL exit code 22
Requested URL: http://localhost/drupal7/cron.php

Please help. Thanks.

===========================================================================
I found a clue. My mail title shows up:

if test -x /usr/share/drupal7/scripts/cron.sh ; then /usr/share/drupal7/scripts/cron.sh ; fi

So, I check the path and get known cron.sh this file. I paste the content. I am not good at bash. What is this bash meaning for? Would you simply explain this? I would thank you very much.

```
#!/bin/sh

for site in /etc/drupal/7/sites/* ; do
    BASE_URL=""
    CRON_KEY=""
    FULL_URL=""

    if [ ! "`basename $site`" = "all" ]; then
            for file in $site/baseurl.php $site/settings.php; do
                    [ -f "$file" ] && BASE_URL=`grep '^$base_url' $file | cut -d"'" -f2`
                    [ "X$BASE_URL" != "X" ] && break
            done

            for file in $site/cronkey.php $site/settings.php; do
                    [ -f "$file" ] && CRON_KEY=`grep '^$cron_key' $file | cut -d"'" -f2`
                    [ "X$CRON_KEY" != "X" ] && break
            done

            if [ "X$BASE_URL" = "X" ] ; then
                    if [ -f "$site/settings.php" ]; then
                            BASE_URL='http://localhost/drupal7'
                    else
                            break
                    fi
            fi

            if [ "X$CRON_KEY" = "X" ] ; then
                    FULL_URL="$BASE_URL/cron.php"
            else
                    FULL_URL="$BASE_URL/cron.php?cron_key=$CRON_KEY"
            fi

            if curl -S --fail --silent --compressed --insecure --location $FULL_URL ; then
                    # Success!
                    true
            else
                    echo "Error running the periodic maintenance for      $site: CURL exit code $?"
                    echo "Requested URL: $FULL_URL"
            fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Run cron every** setting only disables Drupal's automatic cron job firing within page requests. This is a lightweight option (previously known as [Poorman's cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/poormanscron)) for sites that have some minor cron tasks that can be handled before serving a page request.

It doesn't disable any external cron requests from crontab, Jenkins, or any other task runner service that might be calling **cron.php**. You will need to configure your server to disable this.